# php 7 + mssql + iis 7.5 не удается подключится

Tags: php, sql-server, веб-программирование, iis-7

Добрый день, уже весь иннет перегуглил, ничего не помогает, осталась вся надежда на вас:

PHP 7, IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008r2
при попытке подключения к MSSQL возникает ошибка:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\inetpub\путь\connect.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\путь\connect.php on line 4
```

в `php.ini` директива `extension=php_mssql.dll` отсутствует, самого `php.ini` в этом релизе нет, его заменили на `php.ini-development` и `php.ini-production`

Сам скрипт:

```
$serverName = "mssql02\";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {      
     echo "Соединение удалось.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Соединение не удалось, ошибка:";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

то что нет имени сервера, пользователя, пароля и тд это не ошибка, просто убрал специально

PDO загрузил, закинул в папку ext:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в php конфиге добавил строчку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но оно не хочешь работать

в выводе пхпинфо вообще нет PDO драйверов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ODBC драйвер установил , вот этот 
https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: Ну дак никто не может подсказать :С и в гугле ниче толком нет по этому релизу

Comment: В pdo ни чего и не должно отображаться. Для него другие dll подключаются из архива. Подключайте dll только одного типа: `ts` для `php7ts.dll` и `nts` для `php7.dll`.

Comment: Все решилось проще, переименовал php ded. в php.ini все заработало

Answer (score 1):

Все решилось проще, переименовал php dev. в php.ini все заработало